# Export to xls file format

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, export, xls

I need a JQuery grid with export to xls or a javascript code for export to xlsx file format. I am trying something like this:

```
    function emitXmlHeader(testTypes) {
        var headerRow =  '<ss:Row>\n';
        for (var colName in testTypes) {
            headerRow += '  <ss:Cell>\n';
            headerRow += '    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">';
            headerRow += colName + '</ss:Data>\n';
            headerRow += '  </ss:Cell>\n';        
        }
        headerRow += '</ss:Row>\n';    
        return '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n' + 
           '<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">\n' +
           '<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">\n' +
           '<ss:Table>\n\n' + headerRow;
   };

   function emitXmlFooter() {
       return '\n</ss:Table>\n' +
              '</ss:Worksheet>\n' +
              '</ss:Workbook>\n';
   };

   function jsonToSsXml(data, testTypes) {
       var row;
       var col;
       var xml;

       xml = emitXmlHeader(testTypes);

       for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
           xml += '<ss:Row>\n';

           for (col in testTypes) {
                xml += '  <ss:Cell>\n';
                xml += '    <ss:Data ss:Type="' + testTypes[col]  + '">';
                xml += data[row][col] + '</ss:Data>\n';
                xml += '  </ss:Cell>\n';
           }

           xml += '</ss:Row>\n';
       }

       xml += emitXmlFooter();
       return xml;  
    };

    function download(content, filename, contentType) {
        if (!contentType) contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
        var a = document.getElementById('exportExcel');
        var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", content], {
        'type': contentType
    });
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    };

    function excelExport() {

        var data = [
             {
                  "firstname": "John",
                  "lastname": "Smith",
                  "date": "2015-11-11"
             },
         {
                  "firstname": "Jim",
                  "lastname": "Bains",
                  "date": "2015-11-11",
             }
    ];
        var testTypes = {
              "firstname": "String",
              "lastname": "String",
              "date": "Date"
    };

    var excel = jsonToSsXml(data, testTypes);           
    download(excel, 'test.xls', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    }
```

I get an error opening the xls file. I suppose there is something in the formatting. Can you give me some support?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Grid example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-excel) by Shield UI - with it you can seamlessly setup the Grid to export to Excel 2003 and 2007 (and later) formats.

Their full documentation on the exporting functionality can be found [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/export). It says you can export to PDF too, regardless of the data origin and the control used to render it.